# Testing component depending on setinterval methods [React Testing Library]

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

Is there any way to test component which is updated depending on setinterval function with react testing library?

for example

```
class Counter extends React {
    state = { counter: 0}

    incrementCounter = () => this.setState(({counter}) => counter: counter + 1);

    componentDidMount() {
       setInterval(incrementCounter, 1000);
    }

    render() {
       return <>{this.state.counter}</>
    }
}
```

this component should display increased number every second, so avoiding implementation details testing and checking the component `state` i'd actually like to check if i got proper values rendered.

I guess I could use jest's `advanceTimersByTime` method

```
it('renders increased counter every sec', () => {
   jest.useFakeTimers();

   const { container } = render(<Counter />)

   // render 0 before first iteration
   expect(container.textContent).toBe(0)

   //first iteration
   jest.advanceTimersByTime(1000)
   expect(container.textContent).toBe(1)

   //second iteration
   jest.advanceTimersByTime(1000)
   expect(container.textContent).toBe(1)
})
```

I am not sure if this approach is proper since i do not call React Testing Library's `render` before every `expect` call, or maybe should I implement this testing in the totally different way?

Comment: In cases like these, I usually add 100ms to allow enzyme to render the component as state update will start exactly at 1000ms and will take an additional 100ms to complete and render the component. Try `jest.advanceTimersByTime(1100)`

Answer (score 1):

I think you should consider using [`wait`](https://github.com/kentcdodds/react-testing-library#wait) helper from the **react-testing-library** docs. You can find the description [here](https://github.com/kentcdodds/dom-testing-library/blob/master/README.md#wait).

It should be used with async `await` then and it does have the options for interval that you need:

```
function wait(
    callback?: () => void,
    options?: {
        timeout?: number
        interval?: number
    },
): Promise<void>
```